# Finding solutions to nonlinear wave equations with time-periodic boundary conditions (closed timelike curves)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

Is it known how to solve nonlinear dispersive wave equations, such as the Klein-Gordon equation with a $\phi^4$ interaction with time-periodic boundary conditions? The motivation behind time-periodic boundary conditions is to provide a simplified model of spacetime with closed timelike curves (CTCs). I haven’t been able to find any substantial prior research on the problem. I am also interesting in how CTCs affect wave turbulence, such as in calculating the Kolmogorov-Zakharov spectra and diffusion equations or whether CTCs will cause PDEs that normally show weak wave turbulence to show strong wave turbulence.

So if you have the quartic interaction with Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2} [\partial^\mu \varphi \partial_\mu \varphi -m^2 \varphi^2] -\frac{\lambda}{4!} \varphi^4$ with equations of motions
$\partial^2\varphi+\mu_0^2\varphi+\lambda\varphi^3=0$ defined on  $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{T}^1$,  where $\mathbb{T}$is the torus, is there some standard way of finding solutions? Can an analog of the initial value problem be defined, perhaps with data defined on only part of a Cauchy hypersurface? Will the PDE defined on a spacetime with CTCs show finite time blow-up even when the PDE would not show blow-up without CTCs?